Indexing into torch tensor with variable length indices along an axis
I'm trying to compute the word probabilities of a list of tokenized words according to a language model, and I need some fancy indexing.
My inputs, illustrated with toy example below:

token_list: n_words x max_tokenization_length (e.g., three words where the max tokenization length is 3)
pxhs: n_words x (max_tokenization_length + 1) x |vocabulary|, (e.g. three words, four sets of logits for 3+1 tokens, and dimension 1000 vocab)
next_word_token_ids: list of tokens that constitute a new word (e.g., all tokens that start with a space character).

pxhs = torch.rand((3,4,1000))

pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id
word_token_list = [
    [120, pad_token_id, pad_token_id],
    [131, 132, pad_token_id],
    [140, 141, 142],
]

new_word_token_ids = [0,1,2,3,5]

Desired output is a length 3 list of word probabilities computed as follows:
word 1: pxhs[0, 0, 120] * pxhs[0, 1, new_word_token_ids].sum()
word 2: pxhs[1, 0, 131] * pxhs[1, 1, 132] * pxhs[1, 2, new_word_token_ids].sum()
word 3: pxhs[2, 0, 140] * pxhs[2, 1, 141] * pxhs[2, 2, 142] * pxhs[2, 3, new_word_token_ids].sum()

In practice, I want to index by replacing the first pad_token_id with the new word token ids, and then nothing (this doesn't work as an index, just illustrating):
actual_idx = [
    [[120], new_word_token_ids, [None], [None]],
    [[131], [132], new_word_token_ids, [None]],
    [[140], [142], [143], new_word_token_ids],
]

I wrote a very slow function that does this:
all_word_probs = []
for word_tokens, word_probs in zip(token_list, pxhs):
    counter=0
    p_word=1
    while (counter < len(word_tokens) and 
            word_tokens[counter] != tokenizer.pad_token_id):
        p_word = p_word * word_probs[counter, word_tokens[counter]]
        counter+=1
    new_word_prob = word_probs[counter, new_word_tokens].sum()
    p_word = p_word * new_word_prob
    all_word_probs.append(p_word)

I need something faster, thanks in advance for your help!

Taking your desired output
word 2: pxhs[1, 0, 131] * pxhs[1, 1, 132] * pxhs[1, 2, new_word_token_ids].sum()

The idea is to split up the computation in two parts: the token_list probabilities (pxhs[1, 0, 131] * pxhs[1, 1, 132]) and the new_word_token_ids probabilities (pxhs[1, 2, new_word_token_ids].sum()).
I'm assuming you have access to a n_words-length seq_lens tensor that stores the index of the first padding token for each sequence. I also assume all objects are tensors, and that the maximum sequence length (max_len) below is not too long (otherwise the for-loop will be a bottleneck).
I'm using log probabilities for numerical stability; you should be able to convert back without issue.
n = len(word_token_list)
max_len = seq_lens.max()
seq_idxs = torch.arange(n)
log_pxhs = pxhs.log()

# Step 1:
# Compute the probability of the sequences in `word_token_list`
# (clever indexing could also vectorize this at the expense of intelligibility)
log_p_x = torch.zeros(n)
log_p_x = torch.zeros(n)
for i in range(max_len):
    tok_idxs = word_token_list[:, i]
    log_p_x += log_pxhs[seq_idxs, i, tok_idxs] * (i < seq_lens)

# Step 2:
# Compute the probability of the `new_word_token_ids` at the end of the sequence
v = pxhs.shape[2]
v_mask = torch.isin(torch.arange(v), new_word_token_ids, assume_unique=True)
# mask pxhs to only include nonzero values for `new_word_token_ids`
p_new = pxhs * v_mask
# index those probabilities for the end of the sequence
p_new_given_x = p_new[seq_idxs, seq_lens].sum(1)

# Step 3: compute the final log-probability
print(log_p_x + p_new_given_x.log())

I didn't benchmark things but I think it should lead to a substantial speedup.
